# Why are the result of preg_match not displayed?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, echo

I can't see the results of `preg_match` by regex! Where is the problem?

```
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i',"'".$urls['url']."'", $matches);
    $host = $matches[1];
    preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
echo "from: <p id='long'>{$matches[0]}\n</p>";
}
```

Output:

```
from:
```

Comment: Why are you running two `preg_match()` calls? Also, your `(?:http://)?` will always match as blank because of your `'` in your test string.

Comment: i need show domain name from url .$urls['url'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo parse_url($urls['url'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the input is just an URL you can use [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/parse_url), in your case with the `PHP_URL_HOST` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) ?

and change `"'".$urls['url']."'"` to `$urls['url']`